# Should we delete spammers' accounts?

Tags: discussion, spam, deleted-accounts

We just had a [new user](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4114/user4114) from Nigeria (hah!) post spam as an answer, and then as a comment to their own answer. Sample:

> Loan offer @ 2% Do you need financial help, A loan to pay up bills,
>   debts or start up business of your choice? then your prayer has been
>   answered, contact now with the following information: Full
>   Name.......

etc.

I deleted both, obviously. In cases like this, is it worth suspending the user, or is policy better just to delete the offending account?

Comment: Do you need financial help?  A loan to pay up bills, debts or start up business of your choice? then your prayer has been answered... :)

Comment: @mattytommo I have this incredible urge to flag your comment as spam, I can't imagine why ;)

Comment: http://loyalkng.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/flamethrower.jpg

Comment: Why suspend? In the hope that they see the error in their ways and become a constructive user afterwards? ;)

Comment: @Bart - he is from Nigeria after all, sure, now he wants to offer loans, but soon he might come across the will of a rich distant relative of mine and need to get in touch of me to send me my millions!

Comment: @MarkMayo Hmm, award him a bounty we shall!

Comment: @Pekka웃: Ahhh...reminds me of the good old times over at SU, when only few of us roamed the forests, hunting Spammers down in the woods, dragging them out onto the lovely meadows where they were scorched by High-Precision-Flag-Guided-Diamond-Lasers (with frickin' sharks). Good times...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Suspending creates a paper trail and notifies several SE employees, that is just unnecessary noise.

Just destroy the spammer account, or flag the spam posts to death and ignore the account.

Comment: And user destroyed.  Highly satisfying.

Comment: @MarkMayo With great power, comes great responsibility. *solemn tone*

Comment: Suspending them blocks that email from being used to re-register though. If you destroy then they're free to sign up again and carry on.

Comment: @JonW Most spam users are unregistered, no matter what you do there is no real barrier to just creating another unregistered user.

Comment: @MadScientist yes good point. When spammers are registered then suspension is better, but you're right, if they're unregistered then there is no point.